# Vue list-component vs list of single components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm just starting my Vue journey and I have a question that I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere else. (Maybe I need to take a look at my Google skills aswell)

I have a fresh Laravel project that consists of a view that should show every Wine, a view that should show a single wine, and some Wine CRUD views.

My question is; In my view that shows all the wines in the database, should I make a `<wine-list></wine-list>` component that contains a list of all the wines or should I create a list that contains a bunch of `<wine></wine>` components?

I don't really understand if it's better to make single component or list components.

I also want a view that shows a single wine that has been clicked on in the list. So I wonder if I should make a wine list component, and when you click on a wine in that list component it should show a single wine component.

Please enlighten me

Comment: For the listing, I will suggest you go with `<wine-list></wine-list>` and for displaying single wine you should create a new `blade` file and there you should fetch the particular wine in a component using `<wine></wine>`

Comment: `<wine-list>` takes and array as property and it contains `<wine>` elements. create two components and one includes the other.

Comment: Ahh okay, great. Thank you guys!